# Ng-show not working after routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, cookies

I am having an issue hiding my navigation if you delete the cookie(Token) from the browser after logging in. So you can login and the navigation will show but after deleting the token it will only hide if i refresh the browser. If you just click on the dashboard nav link it routes you back "/" and shows the home.html instead of dashboard.html but it never correctly hides the navigation even though $scope.navigation = false in the javascript.

```
Scenario in Steps: 
1. Go to index.html with template home.html showing and login
2. Delete token from browser
3. Click on Dashboard nav link performAuthCheck is called from dashboard controller
4. performAuthCheck doesnt find cookie so page is routed "/"
5. Login Controller calls  $scope.authenticated = authService.tokenExists();
6. ng-show=authenticated doesnt hide navigation event though $scope.authenticated = false
```

Its almost like the dom needs to reload because once $scope.authenticated = false the html is not aware. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Index.html:

```
<div data-ng-show="authenticated">
                    <li class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                            <li data-ng-class="{'active':selectedTab === 'Dashboard'}" data-ng-click="selectedTab = 'Dashboard'"><a href="/Dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
                            <li data-ng-class="{'active':selectedTab === 'Contacts'}" data-ng-click="selectedTab = 'Contacts'"><a href="/Contacts">Contacts</a></li>
                            <li data-ng-class="{'active':selectedTab === 'LeadSources'}" data-ng-click="selectedTab = 'LeadSources'"><a href="/LeadSources">Lead Sources</a></li>
                            <li data-ng-class="{'active':selectedTab === 'Admin'}" data-ng-click="selectedTab = 'Admin'"><a href="/Admin">Admin</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </div>
```

Module code (app):

```
$routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl: "/Templates/Home.html",
        controller: "lgLoginController"
    })
    .when("/Dashboard", {
        templateUrl: "/Templates/Dashboard.html"
    })
   ...
```

Dashboard Controller:

```
app.controller('dbDashboardController', function($scope, authService) {
    authService.performAuthCheck();
});

Login Controller:

app.controller('lgLoginController', ['$scope', '$http', 'authService',
function ($scope, $http, authService) {

    $scope.authenticated = authService.tokenExists();

    $scope.login = function () {
        code to login...
    };
}]);
```

Auth Service:

```
app.factory('authService', ['$http', '$q', '$cookieStore', '$location',
function ($http, $q, $cookieStore, $location) {

    return {

        tokenExists: function() {
            //Get cookie
            var tokenCookie = $cookieStore.get('_Token');

            if (tokenCookie === undefined) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        },
        performAuthCheck: function () {
            //Get cookie
            var tokenCookie = $cookieStore.get('_Token');

            if (tokenCookie === undefined) {
                $location.url('/');
            }
        },
        loginService : function(username, password) {
            Post for logging in...
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: That's how cookies work -- you need to reload the page completely to see the changes made.

Comment: Really? I'm fighting something that cannot be done?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the lgLoginController controller is firing when you click on the /Dashboard link? Put a javascript console.log('lgLoginController') statement in the controller to verify that it's running as you expect. I don't think it's running again when you go to Dashboard -- if that's the case, the $scope.authenticated value is never getting updated until you reload and it actually runs again.

Comment: Yes the logincontroller is firing. I put in a breakpoint and logged to the console. Thank you for the suggestion